# $L_2$ /$L_1$ norm of Gradient

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, signal-processing, total-variation

The question, briefly:

I am interested in using "Total Variation Denoising" in order to recover a 2-dimensional signal (in particular, an image).  In the existing literature, many authors use the $L_1$ and $L_2$ norms in their denoising algorithms.  For instance, in page 6 of [this paper](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00437581/document), the Variational method is given as:

$$
\min_{u} \lambda F(u) + \frac{1}{2} \int_{\Omega} |u(x) - g(x)|^2 \,dx
$$
where $F(u) = \frac{1}{2}\int_{\Omega}\|\nabla u\|^{2}$. Here, $g:\Omega \to \Bbb R$ is the given signal, and the function $u:\Omega \to \Bbb R$ attained through minimization is meant to be the "denoised" version of this signal.

My questions are as follows:

- What do I get from the $L_2$ norm of the gradient ($F$ in this example)? What do i get back? Do I get back a gradient? (i think so). But How did i manipulate it? What is this square sum of Gradients?
- Some papers use the $L_1$ norm instead of an $L_2$ norm.  Why choose one over the other?  For instance, in [this paper](https://www-pequan.lip6.fr/~bereziat/cours/master/vision/papers/rudin92.pdf), the authors just state that the correct norm for this is $L_1$ not $L_2$. I have heard that the $L_2$-norm "deletes sharp edges" while the $L_1$ norm preserves them, but I don't really understand how.

---

I have used the search function but did not find my answer or I found it and did not understand it.

I have to use the $L_1$ and $L_2$ norm on a 2 Dimensional Signal (image). My topic is Total Variation De-noising. The Total Variation uses $L_1$ Norm. I have look up what the TV is. More likely I believe the TV is already the $L_1$ norm. Because it takes extreme points of a function and sums it up. So it tells me the oscillation of the function. This means how the function moves. (so far I look it up)

Now I should understand what the norm of gradients is. I know the formulas and have look them up!

It is more like to understand what exactly do I calculate with it.

So I have to gradients in $x$ and $y$ and now I make the $L_2$ norm out of them. What do I get? What is this? Why do I do it?

The gradient tells me how the image changes in that point I have the gradient. When I make now an $L_1$ Norm over several points / gradients. I get the gradient which tells me how much the stuff changes (positive and negative gets just summed up) So I know how big the changes are in this point.

I have [this paper](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00437581/document).

Page 7 I got 2 examples in Figure 2: When I go over the points and the colour values I have no denoising. Because i have no connection from my data to the picture. So it is the right thing to use the Gradient because he makes a connection to the picture and the information in the pictures.

When I take a look at the example i can clearly see two things: 
First the colours are not enough no connection 
Second the gradient with the $L_2$ norm makes everything smooth.

I have to understand now why this happen with the $L_2$ Norm. And for this I have to understand what is the $L_2$ Norm of a gradient. What happens there? What do I calculate?

mfg
Christoph

edit: 
I was ask to make my question more clear: 
I know the $L_1$ and $L_2$ for points in a room. That what I want to know is, what is the $L_1$ and $L_2$ for gradients? What comes out. My thought on $L_1$ is that i will sum up all Gradients and get a new Gradient which will point into the Main Direction from all Gradients. (I imagine on images for denoising this is important because the noise will be the only gradient going wrong, and the sum gives me a good gradient which still goes into the right direction). For the $L_2$ I have no idea what there happens. What do I do to the Gradients? how do i sum them up to a new one?

I also should add examples:
[paper with example](https://www-pequan.lip6.fr/~bereziat/cours/master/vision/papers/rudin92.pdf), in fig 1 on this paper we can see the noisy signal. This signal should become a better one. For this reason the authors going to use the $L_1$ Norm. Now the Gradients they use are on the noisy Signal. I expect that they sum up the Gradients of the signal to create a main direction of the Gradient and use this one for denoising. They just stat that the correct norm for this is $L_1$ not $L_2$. I have seen now much examples on papers like in [this paper](https://www-pequan.lip6.fr/~bereziat/cours/master/vision/papers/rudin92.pdf) page 7 Figure 2. $L_2$ is deleting sharp edges $L_1$ is preserving this edges. To understand now why this happen. I try to find out what the $L_2$ norm is doing with my gradients. Because losing sharp edges has to do something with how I just calculate this stuff.

page 6 on [paper](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00437581/document) the Variational method is given as:

$\min_{u} \lambda F(u) + \frac{1}{2} \int_{\Omega} |u(x) - g(x)|^2 \,dx$

The point now is that they are using for the regulation function (term?) now the $L_2$ of the Gradient. they are stating it under Figure 2 as $F(u)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{\Omega}||\nabla u||^{2}$. I would like to understand, what do i get out of this? What do i get back. Do I get back a gradient? (i think so). But How did i manipulate it? What is this square sum of Gradients?

Comment: It would help us if you could organize your thoughts a bit, that is, narrow down exactly what you are trying to do and what your question is.  If this is an assignment from a class, perhaps it would help if you gave us the exact wording of what the professor is asking you to do.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. I have to write a paper over Total Variation Denoising. My  start point was [this paper ][1]. What I know: 
$L_1$ Norm gives me back the sum of the extrem values. Means for points i get the Manhatten distance. 
$L_2$ Norm for points i get the euclidean Distance. Which is the straight line between two points. 

My problem is now: I should find out what do I get, if I use the $L_1$ Norm on Gradients and what do i get when I use $L_2$ norm on gradients. I dont understand it.

[1]:  https://www-pequan.lip6.fr/~bereziat/cours/master/vision/papers/rudin92.pdf

Comment: I think the question "what do I get" is too unclear.  Also, keep in mind that in order to get an answer here, you have to ask things in a way so that the question is clear even to people who have not read the paper that you linked.

Comment: You should clarify what exactly what you mean by "use the $L_1$ norm on gradients". Perhaps it would help if you explain exactly how the author uses the $L_1$ norm or $L_2$ norm of a gradient in "total variation denoising"

Comment: I will add this to my question. Just give me some moments pls :)

Comment: Your edit helps a bit.  Still, you should say what exactly "use the $L_1$ norm on gradients" means.  Is there a formula corresponding to "taking the $L_1$ norm on gradients", or "the $L_2$ for gradients"?  Could you point out a specific formula in the paper where the author "uses the $L_1$ norm on gradients"?

Comment: I have to find out, why the edges disapear with $L_2$ and why $L_1$ they still keep the edges. For this I try to find out, what I am doing to Gradients with this norms.

Comment: The last paragraph gives me what I was looking for.  In particular, $u$ is a function over $\Omega$, which is a subset of $\Bbb R^2$.  The elements of $\Omega$ roughly correspond to pixels, and for any $x \in \Omega$, $u(x)$ corresponds to the color-intensity at that pixel.  By the "using the $L_2$ norm of gradients", you mean using the $L_2$ norm 
$$
\|\nabla u\|_{L_2} = \int_\Omega \|\nabla u\|^2 \,dx
$$
as a measure of the "badness" of the choice of $u$.

Comment: I have taken the liberty of adding a summarized version of your question at the top; I hope that this will make the question understandable to others.  You are of course free to do whatever you like with your question; feel free to change or remove it if you think that I have misrepresented your question.